# maxLengthEnforced still allowing input after reaching maxLength

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a TextField with a `maxLength` of 110 and `maxLengthEnforced` set to true. The issue is that I can keep typing in the text field, and it doesn't display those characters; so if I type 115 characters, you don't see characters 111-115, but I still have to delete the last five before I can delete character 110, while expecting that there's no possible way for characters 111-infinity to even exist. The TextField will not limit the input to 110 so there's "ghost" characters that need to be deleted before being able to delete the visible characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Flutter GitHub repo, [there was a fix pushed to remedy this defect](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/67892/files). It's currently in the dev channel build **1.23.0-18.1.pre**, but is **not** currently in a stable channel release.